# Virtual hosting with apache and tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, virtualhost

I want to host multiple wars and multiple wordpress applications from a single ec2 instance. I managed to host multiple wars or multiple wordpress applications but not both. A use case might be something like this:

Request as www.tomcatA.com should be handed by tomcat for A.war

Request as www.tomcatB.com should be handed by tomcat for B.war

Request as www.ApacheA.com should be handed by apache, application A

Request as www.ApacheB.com should be handed by apache, application B

I managed to create virtual host just for tomcat or just apache. But how can I do this for both apache and tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you could proxy to the tomcat apps and just have different `DocumentRoot` for the apache applications. Something similar to the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.tomcata.com

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/A
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.tomcatb.com

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/B
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.apachea.com

    DocumentRoot /applicationA
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.apacheb.com

    DocumentRoot /applicationB
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: From apache or tomcat? What is in the logs? This is really only an example of how to configure this. I don't know anything about your internal architecture so you'd need to modify each VirtualHost to fit your setup.

Comment: I had to install mod_jk, configure apache to use it, create workers and create virtual hosts like so to make it work ! <VirtualHost *:80>
.......................................
.......................................
JkMount /tomcat-demo* worker1
</VirtualHost *:80>